# Work with same-kind third-party classes in custom code

Tags: oop

Original problem is related to C# but almost all the strongly typed programming language developers will understand.

I have 2 classes from different third-party libraries. Let's say `Location1` and `Location2`. They both are sealed and have `Latitude` and `Longitude` properties of the same type.
I write custom class (say `Clusterizer`) with methods to work with geographical points. The logic is the same for both external libraries my class should be acceptable for both location classes. Everything is OK for methods which get single `lat`/`long` parameters pair. For example:

```
var point = ...
Clusterizer.AddToCluster(point.Latitude, point.Longitude);
```

The problem is with collections. I want to write method to be called like this:

```
Clusterizer.AddClusters(points);
```

or

```
int index = Clusterizer.CalculateClusterIndex(points);
```

Key points:

1. I do not want to create 2 overloads for both `Location1` and `Location2`. Whould be better to stay with the single method for both classes.
2. I'd like both location classes to implement the same interface (say `ILocation` with `Lat` and `Lon` properties) but they don't of course.
3. I can't create derived classes and implement custom `ILocation` because original classes are `sealed`.
4. I prefere stay with the single `Clusterizer` implementation for location classes because logic is the same for both.
5. I'd like also the avoid creating wrapper classes or my own `Location` class because it is rather expencive to create a new collection and convert back.

One of my ideas is to do something like this:

```
public void AddToCluster<T>(IEnumerable<T> points,
    Func<T, double> latitudeGetter,
    Func<T, double> longitudeGetter)
{
}
```

But it is too ugly to use:

```
AddToCluster(points, x => x.Latitude, x => x.Longitude);
```

Do you have better ideas to my problem?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to create 2 overloads? That sounds like by far the simplest approach to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet smth like `M1(Loc1)` and `M2(Loc2)` methods calling the common one `M(loc.Lat, loc.Lon)`?

Comment: Yes, potentially - although I'd probably give the messages the same name. You could make the *implementations* of those methods use the idea at the end, with the functions...